# Adding multiple versions of WinForms control in Visual Studio Toolbox

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, ide, controls, toolbox

I have multiple DLLs of a WinForms control targeted for different versions of .NET Framework and need to add them all in a Visual Studio Toolbox while showing only the one which is most suitable for currently selected version of .NET.

The control have different features when compiled against different versions of .NET, this is why it would be best to show the most "native" version only. For example, the control have some features removed in .NET 4.0 Client Profile or makes use of .NET 3.0 features when available (not avaiable in .NET 2.0).

The problem is that the control have same name and is signed with same Strong Name Key (SNK).

I can modify source code, but what to do to enable all versions of the component to reside in VS Toolbox?